# Test uart at low baudrate fail at bit 8, linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, uart

I'm testing between 2 uart RS485 port at low baud rate, 600bps, 1200bps.

The first round (uart 1 to uart 2) is always accurate. However, the second round (uart 2 to uart 1) is sometimes wrong at bit 8 (I send char, hopefully bit 8 is 0 (initialization is 0 for every bit in sent data) but catching data at bit 8 is 1).
For eg.

send 0x00, receive 0x00

send 0x00, receive 0x80

...

High baud rate (>= 9600) transmission have't have any issue.

Did you used to face same issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can describe a bit better your setup, in particular the hardware side.

From the errors you're getting at low speed only I would say there might be something wrong with the flow control line (drive enable/~read enable). It would help if you have the chance to monitor your bus with a scope. If you do and you can post a couple of snapshots maybe I can offer more help.

Comment: Thanks @Marcos. Actually, I share same driver for both RS485 and RS232. Meanwhile, there is no flow control line enable, just RTS/RS-/RS+ are connected. So I think, data might be only lost in high baudrate configuration.

Comment: You're welcome Jean. Just to be sure we're on the same page: RS485 is half duplex so although there is no flow control line in the bus itself (like for RS232, where you might have RTS/CTS etc.) you do need a drive enable/~read enable on your UART. If you read here you'll find a lot of questions regarding the use of the RTS line on the UART for that purpose (half-duplex control of which device is driving/talking on the bus). Maybe you can explain in more details how you're connecting your UARTs to the bus and what software you're using, in particular if your driver is handling the RTS correctly